# Dearpygui Select File

Tags: python, imgui, dearpygui

i'm wondering if it's possible to use the operating system's default file explorer to browse for files in dearpygui instead of that ugly one`

I couldn't find any solutions online, most of them say to just use dearpygui's file selector

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `tkinter filedialog askdirectory` function.
It's the closest to native dialog. and good enough for most purposes.

There are a ton of C++ libraries that use native interfaces, but I'm not sure if we have python libraries for those.